# How to create Firefox plugin with single button (same like Echofon)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, browser

I want to how to create **Firefox plugin with custom compact menu same like Firefox window**.
Just now I saw in Echofon. Here is the image, and it looks awesome!
[image: Firefox Echofon with single button]

So, Please tell me, how we can create like that in plugin window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a simple solution. One has to remove the default window title bar (via [`chromemargin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/chromemargin)) and replace it by his own (using [`<xul:titlebar>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/titlebar)). And then it has to be styled to look right with all the operating systems and themes (Windows XP regular, Windows XP classic theme, Vista/7 with Aero, Vista/7 without Aero, ...). You can get an impression of the amount of code required by looking at `chrome://browser/skin/browser.css`, search for "appmenu-button" and "titlebar". Keep in mind that you only see the styles for one OS - Firefox uses different themes for different operating systems.

I got an example together that is mostly working on Windows 7 with Aero (dropdown arrow needs to be replaced by a different image and button position is still wrong when the window is maximized). The window itself (`test.xul`) looks like this:

```xml
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test.css" type="text/css"?>

<window
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    title="Test window"
    width="800"
    height="500"
    chromemargin="0,-1,-1,-1">
  <titlebar id="titlebar" allowevents="true">
    <button id="appmenu-button" type="menu" label="Test">
      <menupopup/>
    </button>
    <spacer id="titlebar-spacer" flex="1"/>
    <hbox id="titlebar-buttonbox">
      <toolbarbutton class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-min"
          oncommand="window.minimize();"/>
      <toolbarbutton class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-max"
          oncommand="window.windowState == 1 ? window.restore() : window.maximize();"/>
      <toolbarbutton class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-close"
          oncommand="window.close();"/>
    </hbox>
  </titlebar>


  <description flex="1">window content</description>
</window>
```

And the styles in `test.css` are the following (mostly copied from `browser.css`):

```css
:root {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-win-borderless-glass;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#appmenu-button:hover:active,
#appmenu-button[open] {
  border-radius: 0;
}
#appmenu-button {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -moz-user-focus: ignore;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.7),
               0 1px 1.5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 1.5em .05em;
  margin: 2px 0 2px;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(247,182,82), rgb(215,98,10) 95%);
  border: 2px solid rgba(83,42,6,.9);
  border-top-style: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: rgba(255,255,255,.5) rgba(83,42,6,.9);
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: rgba(255,255,255,.5) rgba(83,42,6,.9);
  -moz-border-right-colors: rgba(255,255,255,.5) rgba(83,42,6,.9);
  margin-bottom: -1px; /* compensate white outer border */
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.25) inset,
              0 0 2px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25) inset;
}
#appmenu-button:hover:not(:active):not([open]) {
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center bottom, farthest-side, rgba(252,240,89,.5) 10%, rgba(252,240,89,0) 70%),
                    -moz-radial-gradient(center bottom, farthest-side, rgb(236,133,0), rgba(255,229,172,0)),
                    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(246,170,69), rgb(209,74,0) 95%);
  border-color: rgba(83,42,6,.9);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1) inset,
              0 0 2px 1px rgba(250,234,169,.7) inset,
              0 -1px 0 rgba(250,234,169,.5) inset;
}
#appmenu-button:hover:active,
#appmenu-button[open] {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(246,170,69), rgb(209,74,0) 95%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset,
              0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset;
}

#appmenu-button > .button-box {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#titlebar-spacer {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#titlebar-buttonbox {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-button-box;
  -moz-margin-end: 20px;
}
:root[sizemode="maximized"] #titlebar-buttonbox {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-button-box-maximized;
}

#titlebar-min {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-button-minimize;
}
#titlebar-max {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-button-maximize;
}
:root[sizemode=maximized] #titlebar-max {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-button-restore;
}
#titlebar-close {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-button-close;
}
```

I opened the window with the following command:

```js
window.open("chrome://.../test.xul", "_blank", "chrome,all,centerscreen,resizable");
```

This is the end result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I will give try and make it as Answer. if it works fine for me. for now +1. Thanks

Comment: @NagaHarishMovva: Feel free to read the answer first. You shouldn't expect that this will just work - because it won't. To have this working properly you need to invest lots of effort, like the Firefox developers did (while Echofon developers didn't, at least for their Firefox extension).

Comment: Yes, it works for me. But, it show my popup window color as black. Yes, developed a sample Plugin with help of my Firefox plugin developer. He guide me very well and I got what I am expecting in result. Thanks for your Ans. I just want to know the magic.