# Drawing the menu in the titlebar

Tags: user-interface, xul

In XUL, how do you draw a menu (or any other content) where the title bar normally is?

This picture is NOT an XUL app, but it illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: Dreamweaver title bar]

Notice how the menu at the top is in-line with the min/max/close buttons.

In the [Mozilla developer reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/drawintitlebar), I see that there is a `drawintitlebar` attribute for the `<window>` element.  However, setting this to 'true' doesn't change anything that I can see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is essentially the same as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565916/785541) - there is no easy way. You cannot just put something into the title bar, you have to replace the OS-provided title bar by your own. So you use `chromemargin="0,-1,-1,-1"` attribute to remove the usual title bar and you put `<xul:titlebar>` as the first element of your window. It should contain the usual minimize/maximize/close buttons (these will look correctly if you use the right `-moz-appearance` styles). Then you will be able to put a menu into the `<xul:titlebar>` element. But you will need lots of code and styles to ensure that your windows look like native windows on all operating systems.

Comment: If Firefox is any indicator then the default titlebar buttons won't look native, at least on Windows ;)

Comment: @Joey: Usually they will. Maybe you have some very unusual configuration or you are not using the default Firefox theme.

Comment: Default FF theme on an uncustomised Windows 7. The margin to the right of the close button is smaller than on all other windows. Same goes for Chrome, but not what I'd call native ;)

Comment: @Joey: Right, two pixels difference... Getting it exactly right will hardly be possible - but nobody will notice it in this case (with the notable exception of one or two nit-pickers).

Comment: Thanks for your response, and you're right: that is the same as the other question.  I didn't think to search through firefox add-on questions.